# Docusign Initial Call Error

Tags: docusignapi

When I run the call using this help guide http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/quick-start/first-api-call/troubleshoot I get an error

'The specified Integrator key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator Key was not specified.'

I followed the instructions for creating the key and changed all of the information in the sample to run the call.

Can anyone help me with this? Why am I getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

That error message means exactly what it's saying -- DocuSign was unable to identify (a valid) Integrator Key in the **X-DocuSign-Authentication** header of your API Request.  This error could be caused by a variety of things:

- Your request doesn't include the **X-DocuSign-Authentication** header.
- The **X-DocuSign-Authentication** header of your request doesn't specify an Integrator Key.
- The **X-DocuSign-Authentication** header of your request specifies an Integrator Key, but it's not specified in the manner that DocuSign expects.
- The **X-DocuSign-Authentication** header specifies an Integrator Key value, but it's not a valid key.

Here's an example of the HTTP Headers from a DocuSign REST API request -- notice that the **X-DocuSign-Authentication** header specifies the Integrator Key (in addition to Username and Password):

```
Host: demo.docusign.net
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"EMAIL_ADDRESS","Password":"API_PASSWORD","IntegratorKey":"INTEGRATOR_KEY"}
Content-Type: application/json
```

If you need further assistance with this, then please update your question to include the HTTP Headers of your problematic API Request. (You can use Fiddler or similar tool to produce a trace of the full API request, including the headers).

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the help guide as it states, and replace the username, password, and integrator key values with your own credentials?  Looking at the [troubleshooting page](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/quick-start/first-api-call/troubleshoot) you referenced, it shows further down what your `cURL` request should look like:

```
curl --request GET 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information'
\ --header 'Content-Type:application/json' \ --header 'Accept:application/json'
\ --header 'X-DocuSign-Authentication:
<DocuSignCredentials>
    <Username>
        john@test.com
    </Username>
    <Password>
        pass1
    </Password>
    <IntegratorKey>
        AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD
    </IntegratorKey>
</DocuSignCredentials>
’
```

You need to replace `john@test.com` with your email, `pass1` with your account password, and `AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD` with your actual integrator key.  If you're not sure how to generate your Integrator Key see this page:

http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/quick-start/first-api-call